# Python asyncio and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a HTTP server handling calls in a multithread environment and in the handling of each HTTP method I need to await for some coroutines execution with await but I'm not able to understand how this can be accomplished without or waiting for the loop or saying that the loop is already being used.

My code is something like this:

```py
import asyncio
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class HTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler): # HTTP Server
    def do_POST(self):
        ...
        await for something

class ThreadingSimpleServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

class Service():
    def __init__(self, address='localhost', port=8000) -> None:
        self.server = ThreadingSimpleServer((args.address, args.port), HTTPRequestHandler)

    def run(self):
        self.server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    service = Service()
    try:
        service.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

My question is how do I do asyncio awaits inside different threads without blocking the main loop and taking advantage of the multithreading that the ThreadingSimpleServer class offers.

Best regards,
Nuno

Comment: Try `asyncio.run` in a thread except the main one.

Comment: Ordinarily, you would do async I/O *or* multithreading, not both together. If each request gets a thread dedicated to it, then what advantage do you think you gain by having those threads use async I/O?

Comment: In other words: just pick an async web-serving API, like FastAPI or Sanic, isntead of trying to bend the simplistic, but hard to use, built-in http-server to run async code. 

What you want can be done, but it would be a complicated setup, with entangled code - while the async functions you want to consume are designed to make things simpler - but if you run then in an async context.

Comment: @jsbueno thank you for your suggestion on the FastAPI, it seems that with that I can accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Using FastAPI looks very promising, thank you @jsbueno for your tip.

```
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import uvicorn

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    app.state.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    yield
    app.state.executor.shutdown()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.post("/get/files/messageid/{channelid}/{messageid}")
async def information(info : Request, channelid, messageid):
    request = await info.json()
    await asyncio.sleep(20)


class Service():
    def __init__(self, address='localhost', port=8000) -> None:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        ...
        self.args = parser.parse_args()

    def run(self):
        uvicorn.run(app, port=self.args.port, host=self.args.address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    service = Service()
    try:
        service.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```